# How can i authenticate the nodejs application using ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-services, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a web service for my phone gap application.

Backend is written in nodejs. They have used Passport ,
 **local_login** method for the same. which is giving me access_token as well.

I am able to login and able to fetch access token using phone gap application.

How can i fetch other data, which is required session authentication using Phone gap

any idea ?

Comment: You're able to authenticate and get an access token? Which Passport strategy are you using? Can't seem to find "local_login" as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **passport-http-bearer**

```
passport.use(new BearerStrategy(
  function(token, done) {
    User.findOne({ token: token }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user, { scope: 'all' });
    });
  }
));


Authenticate Requests


app.get('/profile', 
  passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
  });
```

for more details visit this link https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer